# difference between multiple inheritance and multilevel inheritance

Tags: python, oop

one non mature question on inheritance :-)

Say I have  classes

```
class A (B)
 {code}



class B(C)
 {code}

class C(object)
 def function1()
   {code}
```

I can access function1() with following code

```
obj=A()
obj.function1()
```

Since we have multilevel inheritance, we can get it.

I believe I can do the  same using multiple inheritance ? like

```
class A(B,C)  ?
```

What is the difference here?

Where can i get true use case of multilevel inheritance over multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Base1:
    pass

class Base2:
    pass

class MultiDerived(Base1, Base2):
    pass
```

this is an example of **multiple inheritance** . In that a single class can inherit multiple classes . 
**In multilevel if you have a class**

```
class A 
 {code}

class B (A)
 {code}

class C (B)
{code}
```

in this you Inherit class A property in class C when you Inherited class b . so if a class has inherited some class and you dont want to inherit property of superclass than **multiple inheritance** is used .

for more info with diagram refer to this link :- https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/multiple-inheritance

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example both definitions of class A will have the same effect. But if you add function1 to class B as well, then you can decide which version of function1 will be called from class A, by adjusting multiple inheritance order when defining class A.

So you can do this like this:

```
class A(B,C)
```

or like that:

```
class A(C,B)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem with multiple inheritance is function overloading. Imagine this:

```
class A:
    def test(self):
        print("class A")

class B:
    def test(self):
        print("class B")

class C(A, B):
    pass

c = C()
c.test()
```

Can you guess what the output will be? (it's `class A`). In case of multilevel inheritance you have more control over overriding methods. It's less likely for you to make mistake using multilevel inheritance. You can simple overlook that your parent classes are implementing same method for your child class.
But to be honest, as long as you `know` how to handle multiple inheritance in python and you know the problems with it - you should be fine using either. Check [official python documentantion](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance) for the multiple inheritance.